# recyclerView ClickListener return null after notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

i am using a recyclerView and loading the data from database.The recyclerView item have 2 buttons. The recyclerView loads fine and clicks work fine for the following code.

```
allData=db.getCatData(CATEGORYLIST_CIDD,1);
textlistadapter = new TextListAdapter(getActivity(), allData);
recyclerView.setAdapter(textlistadapter);
```

later i rearrange the adapter data for displaying the data in descending order by using this code

```
    db=new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    allData=db.getCatData(CATEGORYLIST_CIDD,order_id);
    textlistadapter = new TextListAdapter(getActivity(), allData);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(textlistadapter);
    textlistadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Now the items are rearranged on the recyclerView, but the onShareButtonClickListener returns null, here is the code of the adapter.

```
private OnShareButtonClickListener onShareButtonClickListener;
public interface OnShareButtonClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, Pojo obj, int position);
}
public void setOnShareButtonClickListener(final OnShareButtonClickListener onShareButtonClickListener) {
    this.onShareButtonClickListener = onShareButtonClickListener;
}
```

the click listener code is here

```
 holder.bt_share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Snackbar.make(view, "Share Clicked", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (onShareButtonClickListener != null) {
                onShareButtonClickListener.onItemClick(view, c, position);
            }
        }
    });
```

The click does not work since the onShareButtonClickListener is null.

The same code works well for the first time and once i change the order then the click events are not working, all other functions are working well.

Comment: Got a hint, but i cant understand it. "in refreshData you create new instance of adapter, when you create new instance all data will be reset, don't create new instance and just refresh your data and call notifyDataSetChange"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should only need to do this once:

```
textlistadapter = new TextListAdapter(getActivity(), allData);
recyclerView.setAdapter(textlistadapter);
```

later on, if you want to update/change the data, then you should do something like this:

```
textlistadapter.setListItems(allData);
textlistadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Where `setListItems()` is a public method in your adapter, an example like this:

```
public void setListItems(List<> allData) {
    this.data.clear();
    this.data.addAll(allData);
}
```

Comment: works fine, but the recyclerView loading animation has gone.

Comment: I'm sure there's a workaround for that, in a new question then =)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to understand what you are doing wrong. You populate an array which will feed your adapter with data, that meaning that, after setting the adapter, if you want it's data to change, you only need to change the array you populated the data with, and notify the adapter for the data change.

For example:

```
myData = db.getData();
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,myData);
recyvlerview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Now every time you want to change the data, you only need to change your myData and notifity the adapter

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChange();
```

Basically instead of doing this:

```
db=new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
allData=db.getCatData(CATEGORYLIST_CIDD,order_id);
textlistadapter = new TextListAdapter(getActivity(), allData);
recyclerView.setAdapter(textlistadapter);
textlistadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This should suffice

```
db=new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
allData=db.getCatData(CATEGORYLIST_CIDD,order_id);
textlistadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: oh yes, is it wrong to load the new data to the adapter?

Comment: fine, i am using List<Pojo> allData ; How to rearrange the allData in first to last and last to first and Random

Comment: You can do it but it doesn't mean it's the correct way of doing it, but if you do you won't need to notify your adapter for data change because you are already giving it the new data (and obviously a new adapter since you initialize it again)

Comment: Nothing happens with db=new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
allData=db.getCatData(CATEGORYLIST_CIDD,order_id);
textlistadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();